# Devise on Rails : Invalid session redirection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

If the session is invalid , devise redirects the user to /users/sign_in .How to make devise redirect the user to /login ?

Comment: Invalid session redirection, you mean after sign_out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From device [documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes#another-simple-way-to-do-the-same-thing)

Change `routes.rb` devise_for section to this

```
devise_for :users, path: '', path_names: { sign_in: 'login' }
```

Comment: I do not want to change anything for failure. Just need to change the login url.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the following in your routes.rd

```
devise_scope :user do
 get "/login" => "devise/sessions#new"
end
```

this is available in documentation provided with device https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes